# Write out $( \mathbb{Z}_2, +) \times ( \mathbb{Z}_2, +)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

After just learning the basics of group theory and cyclic groups, I would like to write down an example of a Carthesian product of 2 cyclic groups in an attempt to have a more visual representation. I have just learned the theory of this subject and am not familiar with it yet, so bear with me!

Is it possible to write out  $( \mathbb{Z}_2, +) \times ( \mathbb{Z}_2, +)$ in a bit of detail, perhaps even with some extra commentations or guidelines ?

Comment: It’s just the set of ordered pairs whose entries are the numbers 0 and 1.  $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$

Comment: For fun, here's another way to think about $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ (the klein four group): the set $\{1,a,b,c\}$ with commutative multiplication where every element times itself is $1$ (e.g. $c^2=1$) and the product of any two distinct letters is the third one (e.g. $ab=c$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are particularly lucky, as you have chosen a *finite* group, so we certainly can write it out.

First, what does its elements look like? In general, for two groups A and B, the elements are exactly the pairs (a,b), with $a \in A, b \in B$.

What do these pairs look like in our case? Well, since $$Z_2 = \{0,1\}$$ (Considered as a set, i.e we dont care that the formal definition of a group is a pair whose first coordinate is a set and the second coordinate an operation on the set - I only described the first coordinate, assuming that we agree on the operation anyway).

So the pairs we are looking for are things like $$(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$$ Frankly, these are all the elements in the group $Z_2 \times Z_2$! In other words - we have written out the group. (lets call it $G$ from now)

(If you recall, the Cartesian product of two finite sets of size $n$ and $m$ will be a new set of size $nm$, so we expect to find four elements in our new group).

**Now that we know what the elements are - lets do some computing!** First, what is the identity element in $G = Z_2 \times Z_2$? In general, this is the pair $(0_a,0_b)$ where $0_a$ is the identity in A, and $0_b$ is the identity in B. In this case, this gives us that the identity in $G$ must be $(0,0)$.

To give you some idea of how the group operations work in this case - let us compute $(1,0) + (1,1)$. We simply work coordinate-wise, following the definition of products of groups. The result is then $(1 + 1, 0 + 1) = (0,1)$.

I hope this helps!

Comment: So if i now look at $Z_2 \times Z_3$
With $$Z_2 = \{0,1\}$$ and $$Z_3 = \{0,1,2\}$$
Then $Z_2 \times Z_3$ = $$ \{(0,0);(0,1);(0,2);(1,0);(1,1);(1,2)\} ?$$
If so I still fail to see how this is any different from the Cartesian product of two sets of numbers (being {0,1} and {0,1,2}), in other words whats the difference between a Cartesian product of two finite sets of numbers and the Cartesian product of an actual group?

Comment: @Michelle_B you could add your comment to your question or ask a separate question.

Comment: The difference is that a group carries more structure than a set in the sense that a group is a set along with an operation on the set. Thus the product of the groups $Z_2 \times Z_3$ is a new group, with the elements being as you described, but also with an operation that allows us to add elements. You cannot a priori add elements in sets. You can, however, in groups. That is the difference.